# Aggregate total number of orders using Invoice Line Items

Tags: sql

I am trying to count the number of unique booking by each Customer by looking at the `invoice_id`, however they aren't producing the correct results.

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE invoice_line_items (
    invoice_id int,
    customer_id int,
    tstamp datetime
);
```

Data

```
INSERT INTO invoice_line_items (invoice_id, customer_id, tstamp)
VALUES ('1', '123', '2018-12-21 10:00:00'),
('1', '123', '2018-12-21 10:00:00'),
('2', '123', '2018-12-22 10:00:00'),
('2', '124', '2018-12-22 10:00:00'),
('3', '124', '2018-12-22 10:00:00'),
('4', '124', '2018-12-22 10:00:00'),
('5', '124', '2018-12-22 10:00:00'),
('5', '124', '2018-12-22 10:00:00');
```

Query

```
select customer_id, count(*) as number_of_orders
from invoice_line_items
where tstamp >= '2018-01-01'
group by customer_id, invoice_id
```

Desired Output

```
customer_id | number_of_orders 
123         | 2          
124         | 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include `invoice_id` in `group by` :

```
select customer_id, count(distinct invoice_id) as number_of_orders
from invoice_line_items
where tstamp >= '2018-01-01'
group by customer_id;
```

Use `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()` to find unique booking.